# Assigning NSMutabledictionary to NSArray

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
if(NSMutableDictionary[NSDictionary[@"key"]]==NULL) {
    NSMutableDictionary[NSDictionary[@"key"]]=[[NSArray alloc] init];
}
```

How can I declare this into Swift?

Answer (score -4):

Try below code:

```
let dict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionary: ["key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"])

let mutableDict:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: ["dict":dict])

for(var i:Int=0; i < mutableDict.count; i++)
{
     let dic:NSDictionary? = mutableDict["dict"] as? NSDictionary

     if((dic != nil) && (dic?.valueForKey("key1") == nil))
     {
         dic?.setValue(NSArray(), forKey: "key1")
     }

}
```